# Why would mapped type trigger a compilation error when called within class

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Here is my sample code.

Calling `get` within the class triggers an error while calling the method outside works fine.

Any idea why ?

```
type DefinedKeys<T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: K
}

class MyAbstractClass {
  get<K extends keyof this & DefinedKeys<this>>(key: K): this[K] {
    return this[key];
  }
}

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
  foo: string = "ok";
  optional?: string;

  test() {
    this.get('foo'); // Doesn't work 
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();
const yepItsWorks: string = instance.get("foo"); // Ok
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdhAJgaQiAzgHgBUA%20KAXigGtsB7eKAbwCgooBtDKFSmugqAQxxQArsjQIU6KBAAewCGKEF2AXSgB%20KKgBuEAE5QAXFAwrjGRgF9GjAMYAbQUICyIAIIAjHMD39bwAGFHHCEmFgBzCGA8Dll5RW4QWihgAAtEIQAyWAlUTGx8NIyiIgAKKhBzAEpjIpxVBmYWKD0o4T1kFPT6ipUAbibraztglxAgp2k5BTQxz29ffwmQxpZ4ampjBZRwsigAImoKfYGWajBgRGpkfnt1LZ8dgab5b1Kq1ea6gDpI4FKAOTragAqp9KAAeghsGoEBwyABwCgAHdqHoKFBBlYbLZrt5OMhvPxkLZoORUMioK5ljh3gNcYSkSAIGAAJLAHAAdTRFBwDz0Oz2KCJJIgvyipX2wP2YMh0IA8hRGEA)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that withing `test` the execution context is not known.

TypeScript assumes correctly that you could call the method with a different `this` using `instance.test.call(otherThis)` or similar. If you explicitly type `this`, it works.

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
  foo: string = "ok";
  optional?: string;

  test(this: MyClass) {
    this.get('foo'); // Works now
  }
}
```

This is not very consistent though - the following should also bind `this`, but it does not work as expected

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
  foo: string = "ok";
  optional?: string;

  test = () => {
    this.get('foo'); // Doesn't work 
  }
  
}
```